# Obtaining HashSet and Dictionary, grouping by nested property, from List in C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, set, grouping

Sorry I am a newbie in C#, I come from Java 8.

I was checking the code in C#,

In namespace `IBM.Watson.Assistant.v1.Model`

```
public class LogCollection
{
    public LogCollection();
    public List<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public LogPagination Pagination { get; set; }
}
```

In the same namespace the classes:

class `Log`

```
public class Log
{
    public Log();
    public MessageRequest Request { get; set; }
    public MessageResponse Response { get; set; }
    public string LogId { get; set; }
    public string RequestTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string ResponseTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string WorkspaceId { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

class `MessageResponse`

```
public class MessageResponse
{
    public MessageResponse();
    public MessageInput Input { get; set; }
    public List<RuntimeIntent> Intents { get; set; }
    public List<RuntimeEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    public bool? AlternateIntents { get; set; }
    public Context Context { get; set; }
    public OutputData Output { get; set; }
    public virtual List<DialogNodeAction> Actions { get; }
}
```

And the class `Context`

```
public class Context : DynamicModel<object>
{
    public Context();
    public string ConversationId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> System { get; set; }
    public MessageContextMetadata Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have

```
List<IBM.Watson.Assistant.v1.Model.Log> listLog = logCollection.Logs;
```

I would like to get the distinct `ConversationId` into a HashSet (or get a `HashSet` from nested property of object `List`).

In `Java 8` I would use:

```
Set<String> setConversationId = listLog.stream()
    .map(log -> log.getResponse().getContext().getConversationId())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

In C# - can I do something like this?

```
HashSet<string> setConversationId = new HashSet<string>(listLog.HOW_TO_GET_ConversationId_FROM_Context_FROM_Response);
```

Now, I would like to group the logs by `ConversationId` into a dictionary.

In Java 8 is something like:

```
public Map<String, List<Log>> getMapFromList(List<Log> listLog)
{
    Map<String, List<Log>> map = listLog
        .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            log -> log.getResponse().getContext().getConversationId(), 
            Collectors.mapping(log -> log, Collectors.toList())
            ));
    return map;
}
```

In C#

```
public Dictionary<string, List<Log>> getDictionaryFromList(List<Log> listLog)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<Log>> dictionary = listLog
        .???????;
    return dictionary;
}
```

How to group data into a dictionary by nested property of some list?

**NOTE**: I prefer functional/lambda instead of Linq response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question. I am guessing you just want `GroupBy`, and `ToDictionary`, which will produce a `Dictionary<string,List<Log>>`

Given

```
var list = new List<Log>(){...};
```

Usage

```
var dict = list
   .GroupBy(x => x.Response.Context.ConversationId)
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

To get the HashSet

```
var hashSet = list
   .Select(x => x.Response.Context.ConversationId)
   .ToHashSet();
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[`GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TKey>`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key
> selector function.

[Enumerable.ToDictionary Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0)

> Creates a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @QA_Col updated, i am not sure that is what you want though, However it will get distinct `ConversationId` into a `HashSet`, which is itself unique